# HL7 Fhir: create relationship between Patient and Location

Tags: resources, hl7-fhir

In Fhir, how i can create relationship between resource Patient and resource location(room, bed...)? I can´t find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the encounter resource to represent where the patient is

Comment: Ok, i see.   I think Patient should have reference to Location....  This way looks like me "strange"...  Thanks